# Unable to backpropagate through torch.rfft

Tags: pytorch

I have two losses: one the usual L1 loss and second one involving `torch.rfft()`

```
def dft_amp(img):
    fft_im = torch.rfft( img, signal_ndim=2, onesided=False )
    fft_amp = fft_im[:,:,:,:,0]**2 + fft_im[:,:,:,:,1]**2
    return torch.sqrt(fft_amp)

l1_loss = torch.nn.L1Loss()

loss  = l1_loss(pred,gt) + l1_loss(dft_amp(pred),dft(gt_amp))

loss.backward()
```

This runs for the 1st iteration with both losses not bein being `nan` but the loss from 2nd iteration onwards becomes `nan`.

If however only the simple L1 loss is kept and `l1_loss(dft_amp(pred),dft(gt_amp))` is omitted, the training proceeds normally.

Does `torch.rfft()` supports backpropagation? I am using `pytorch 1.4.0`

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some issue with `torch.sqrt()` and not with the `torch.rfft()`. `torch.sqrt()` cannot handle very small values. Thus in the above code replace

`return torch.sqrt(fft_amp)`

with

`return torch.sqrt(fft_amp + 1e-10)`

and the `NaN` values will vanish away.

Though this solution works, it would be nice if someone digs in why square roots are problematic for digital computations.

Comment: the derivative of sqrt(x) is 1/sqrt(x), which is bad when x is very small